# Count ou Count()

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Tendo uma lista, qual melhor forma de saber o número de itens nessa lista e qual a diferença?

```
if (minhaLista.Count > 0) ;
```

ou

```
if (minhaLista.Count() > 0) ;
```

Comment: Tá de olho, hein =D

Comment: @jbueno sempre.

Comment: Boa pergunta...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A melhor forma é sempre usar `Count`, ela é incrementada sempre que um item é adicionado à lista e decrementada sempre que um item é removido.

A diferença entre os dois é que [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) é uma propriedade de `List` e [`Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx) é um método de extensão do namespace `System.Linq`.

No caso de `List`'s, o método `Count()` verifica se o objeto é realmente um `ICollection` e depois retorna a propriedade `Count` (em outros casos ele pode executar algum algoritmo para obter a contagem). Usando diretamente a propriedade você acaba evitando esta verificação.

[Aqui](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1191) você pode encontrar o fonte do método (repare na terceira linha)

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) 
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    ICollection<TSource> collectionoft = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (collectionoft != null) return collectionoft.Count;
    ICollection collection = source as ICollection;
    if (collection != null) return collection.Count;
    int count = 0;
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        checked {
            while (e.MoveNext()) count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

De maneira geral sempre que puder usar a propriedade `Count` é melhor porque o acesso é direto. A expectativa é que ela sempre seja O(1).

[`Count()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) é um método de extensão do LINQ, portanto só pode usar em objetos que implementem `IEnumerable` que poderá executar algum algoritmo para obter a contagem. Se o objeto em questão implementar a interface `ICollection` ele fará justamente a leitura da propriedade `Count`, o resultado será o mesmo e o tempo de resposta quase idêntico, mas bem ligeiramente mais lento por ter uma indireção. Mas ambos terão complexidade O(1). Note que isto não é garantido usando este método, depende do contexto.

O [fonte dele pode ser visto no Reference Source do .NET Framework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1191). [Veja também do .NET Core (.NET 5 pra frente)](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,577032c8811e20d3) (tem que fuçar nos arquivos parentes já que ali está mais organizado.

Comment: Vou usar o link do source na minha resposta. Espero que não se importe =)

Comment: Claro que não, ele público.

Answer (score 8):

O `Count` é uma propriedade manipulada pela sua lista, que é incrementada conforme você aplica um `Add` na lista, ou seja, você tem um acesso direto ao valor ao usa-la.

O `Count()` é um método de extensão que vem do namespace `System.Linq`, sua implementação consiste em varrer o `IEnumerable` e efetuar a contagem (ou tentar buscar a propriedade `Count`, caso seja uma implementação vinda de `ICollection`), ou seja, no fim eles acabam usando a mesma propriedade nesse cenário. Aqui está a implementação dele:

```
  public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        ICollection<TSource> collectionoft = source as ICollection<TSource>;
        if (collectionoft != null) return collectionoft.Count;
        ICollection collection = source as ICollection;
        if (collection != null) return collection.Count;
        int count = 0;
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            checked {
                while (e.MoveNext()) count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

O melhor a se usar é o `Count` neste caso.

Comment: Count() não faz a contagem em listas, o próprio código mostra isso

Comment: Eu estava justamente corrigindo isto agora...

Comment: Show! +1 agora.